# Determine the datatable index of the row clicked in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a GridView in ASP.NET page. The GridView is bound to a dataset/datatabe.  One of the columns of the grid is a command button and the gridview has method OnRowCommand (e.g. OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand") specified.

When user clicks on the button in the grid, the method GridView_RowCommand fires.  I would like to find the index to the DataTable for the row where button was clicked. Note, that I am not looking for index to the GridView row but rather the index to the DataTable bound to the GridView.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The `DataTable` is `null` on postback (if you don't store it in Session). So you have an identifier for the row which you could use to find the record, but you don't have an index of the row in the table.

Comment: Why do you need it at all?

Comment: The GridView has only a few columns (that is fewer than the actual DataTable has). When user clicks in the row I need values of the DataTable columns other than those that are used in the GridView. 
So how can I get to all the data (all columns) of the "row"?

Comment: One way is: pass the primary key of the row via `CommandArgument` to `RowCommand`. You get it with from the `GridViewCommandEventArgs` parameter. Then you can get the record from database or from session(if the table is stored in session what is recommended only in intranet). Here are some ways(VB): http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/01/08/get-primary-key-on-row-command-gridview.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter  I was hoping to not to have to store the table in a session. And also I was hoping that I won't have to make the "trip" back to the database.  But I guess I have no other way to do it. Thank you very much for the sample code. And for your help!

Comment: Why don't you hide the columns that you don't want to show? Then you can access it's values anyway (`BoundField` via `row.Cells[colIndex].Text` and `TemplateField` via `row.FindControl("ControlID")`).

Comment: I think hiding the columns could be the better approach than session or calling database.  I will try this approach.  When you are saying 'hiding a column' do you mean to set the column Visible to false?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options and it depends on the amount of data you are binding to the gridview, one you could save the dataset/datatable to Session[""] as you bind or you could retrieve the data from the database again once you have the unique id of the row.  You could create the following on your gridview:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomer" runat="server"
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="yourId" onrowcommand="gvCustomer_RowCommand">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAction" runat="server" Text="Do Something" CommandName="yourEvent" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

then in the code behind for the RowCommand event have:

```
    protected void gvCustomer_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {    
        if (e.CommandName == "yourEvent")
        {
           var row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
           int rowId = Convert.ToInt32(gvCustomer.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["yourId"]);
            }
    }
```

At this point you have the id which you could either query the database again or access the data source object that you save in to session before binding to the gridview

Or another alternative is:

```
<asp:LinkButton CommandArgument='<%#Eval("PrimaryKey")%>' />
```

Then you can get the arg with e.CommandArgument in the gvCustomer_RowCommand method